# Merchant identify certificate for apple pay on web via Authnet payment gateway

Tags: authorize.net, applepay-web

I am integrating apple pay in my website via authnet payment gateway. I have generated the csr file from authnet and uploaded to apple "Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate" and successfuly activated it. But for integrating the apple pay on web, it showing that need to generate the "Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate" also. When i try to generate it, asking for the csr file. Is this file we will get from authnet? or i need a mac for this one?